# Drupal Render array facebook like button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, drupal

So i have a form that has a facebook like button on it. It renders perfectly the first time a form is rendered. However if I submit the form and it gets rerendered, bad thing happen. I either get a blank div or a div waaay off center that doesn't respond to FB.Event.subscribe. Does anyone have any pointers as to how to make this work? I just want the button to render correctly every time the form gets rerendered.

Here's my render array:

```
    'facebook' => array(
      '#id' => 'wefwefwef',
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="igd_social_box">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('fb-like'),
        'data-href' => array($url),
        'data-layout' => array('button'),
        'data-colorscheme' => array('dark'),
        'data-action' => array('like'),
        'data-share' => array(TRUE),
        'data-show-faces' => array(FALSE),
        )`
```

And the JS is:`

```
Drupal.behaviors.social_facebook = { 
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    //Facebook Like
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: blahblahblah,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
      });
    };
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function() {
      alert('Please work!!');
    });
    jQuery('.fb-like').once(function() {
      (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if(d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script');   
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
      }(document));
    });
  };
});`
```

Comment: Have you first of all ensured that your HTML is valid?

Comment: Ya, the html is valid. It works the very first render, but when I submit and re-render the array (Through AJAX), it breaks.